# Send HTTP request when a computer is added to Active Directory

Tags: directory, active-directory, ldap

I'm going to start working with Active Directory (first time in my life) with python ldap3 library. I've searched the internet for a while but couldn't find any solution for my question. I want to send a request when a computer is added to AD. I've found [this event](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4741) that might solve my problem but I've no idea what is this or how can I use this for my problem.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an event in the Windows Security Event Log on the domain controller.

Windows does allow you to trigger a scheduled task on an event. To do what you want to do, you could set up a scheduled task on each domain controller.

In Task Scheduler:

1. Click "Create Task"
2. Click the "Triggers" tab, then "New..."
3. For "Begin the task", select "On an event"
4. In "Log", select "Security, and for "Event ID" put "4741"
5. Click "OK"

Then on the "Actions" tab is where you tell it what you want it to do when that event happens. You can run anything you want. You can write a PowerShell script if you want. Just search Google for ["run PowerShell script from scheduled task"](https://www.google.com/search?q=run+PowerShell+script+from+scheduled+task) if that's the way you want to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this as soon as possible.